# How to hide url from get method in php

Tags: php

How to hide url of get method in php?
I am using get method to bill print but while printing, I am getting url on print page and I want to hide url from print page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just uncheck Headers and Footers on Printing Pop-up in Chrome/ ... etc[image: Header and footer on printing pop-up]

Comment: May I do this using php  or any other language?

Comment: You can not due to security settings in browser but you only turn this off one, after that browser will remember this setting